# Angular can start button cannot stop the interval

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular13

I am using Angular and I have this code:

App.component.ts

```
started: boolean = false;

…

startStop() {
    if (!this.started) {
      setInterval(()=> { this.test() }, 1000); // not started so start the interval   
      this.started = true;
    } else if (this.started) {
      this.started = false;  // Its started so stop it');
      clearInterval();
    }
  }


test() {
  // do stuff only via interval if started
}
```

Then I have a button that turns it on and off

app.component.html

```
<button (click)=“startStop()”>Start / Stop</button>
```

The interval turns on but not off eventhough the variable "started" is changed to false.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `clearInterval` works. What if you have several intervals ? Which one will it stop ?

`setInterval` returns an id that you should pass to `clearInterval`

```js
startStop() {
    let intervalId
    if (!this.started) {
      intervalId = setInterval(()=> { this.test() }, 1000); // not started so start the interval   
      this.started = true;
    } else if (this.started) {
      this.started = false;  // Its started so stop it');
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }
```